# Any known pattern to mark a WPF routed event as handled ONLY within the scope of a class?

Tags: .net, wpf, events

I have a MouseHandler class that handles the mousedown event in all the elements of a grid. Now, once an event is handled for an element I don't want it to be handled for its parents. Of course I could just set e.Handled = true, but that stops the propagation of the event in all the application. I don't want that, if somebody else wants to handle the event they should be able to do it, I just don't want  my MouseHandler class to keep handling the event.

So far the only idea I have is to keep a static list of handled events in my class where I can mark an event as handled, and so before handling an event first I would check if the event is already in this list. But then I have to deal with cleaning up this list. Not a lot of work, but still kind of smelly. I'm just wondering if there's an easier way to deal with this.

### UPDATE

Here's an example of my UI and what I do with it:

```
Grid
-- Textbox
-- Label
-- Content control
   -- DatePicker
   -- StackPanel
      -- Button
-- Image
```

If I click on any of these controls my class handles the MouseDown event in order to show the properties of the clicked control. If I click on the last Button and don't mark the event as handled, it will propagate to the StackPanel - Content control - Grid. That's what I don't want. On the other hand, if I set e.Handled = true, that messes with the button functionality which depends on the MouseDown event.

Comment: `I'm just wondering if there's an easier way to deal with this.` - It seems to me you're trying to reinvent the wheel somewhat. Use a `ListBox` instead.

Comment: @HighCore: I'm not sure what a ListBox has to do with this.

Comment: `I have a MouseHandler class that handles the mousedown event in all the elements of a grid` - sounds like a ListBox to me. What does your mouse event handler do? Post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: @HighCore: See the update to the question.